# MobileOrg App on iPhone: sync not working with Dropbox

Tags: ios

I'm having a problem with MobileOrg app on iphone (Iphone 11, Pro Max IOS 14)

I execute org-mobile-push, which moves my various files to the directory defined by org-mobile-directory. I verify that the files are copied to the directory. One of them (the one I'm really interested in) has a timestamp of the last time it was edited (in this case, yesterday) and it has the correct timestamp. But when I sync on the iphone, the file is not updated and the timestamp in the file is from April. The App says the last sync was today, but the file itself is wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found the answer. The documentation in the MobileOrg app says that the app is expecting the directory to be ~/Dropbox/Apps/MobileOrg, which forces the name of the directory the push. It doesn't matter how org-mobile-push and org-mobile-inbox-for-pull are defined, if you're using Dropbox, their values are forced.

The thing is, it used to work as I'd configured it. I guess the iPhone app was changed. As of about 2020-04-03, which is when it stopped working for me.